# Why are there many PHP-CGI processes?

Tags: php, php-cgi

My webmin server has been running into a memory issue, when I check the memory usage, I found this

[image]

Why are there so many `php-cgi7.4` processes? Is this normal?

Comment: Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply. Some related topics may be asked on Webmasters SE

Comment: FastCGI is a protocol that allows the web server (on Windows or not) to forward incoming HTTP requests to the background processing processes (`php-cgi` in PHP). I wrote about how PHP FastCGI works on Windows in https://halfblood.pro/who-should-be-contacted-for-php-on-iis-issues-c80b90bd365 and you can see the similarity. To analyze memory issue, you need to determine whether each process uses the right amount of memory but that's application specific and you should involve the web app developers/vendors for guidance.